# Iterating and using find() in a map c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, find

I have a map storing a "job" as a key and a "name" as the value it stores.

```
map<string, string>dutyAndJob; 
map<string,string>::iterator it;
```

I'm basically trying to look through this map for a particular "name".
If the name isn't there, it shouldn't enter this loop, however, for some unknown reason, it always enters this loop:

```
string name = "Bob";

it = dutyAndJob.find(name);
if (it == dutyAndJob.end())
{
    cout << "Testing : " << name << endl;
}
```

For some reason, it would still enter this loop even though there isn't a Bob stored in the map.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This code prints out "Testing : Bob" even though "Bob" is not actually stored in the map.

Comment: An `if` statement isn't a loop.

Comment: The find member function is for finding **keys**. You say that "name" is the **value**. Find can't find that. You'll need to look at each item's value to see if it is "Bob".

Answer (score 4):

```
if (it == dutyAndJob.end())  
{  
  cout << "Testing : " << name << endl;  
}
```

should be:

```
if (it != dutyAndJob.end()) // Does it refer to a valid association
{  
  cout << "Testing : " << name << endl;  
}
```

Notice the change from `==` to `!=` indicating that the key was found in the map. The iterator `it` is only equal to `dutyAndJob.end()` if the key was **not** found.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying to get it so that if the key was NOT found in the map, then enter this loop. That is why I used the ==

Comment: @Vincent `dutyAndJob.find()` returns `dutyAndJob.end()` if the name was not found. So `it == dutyAndJob.end()` is true when the name is *not* in the map. You have to invert the condition if you want to execute the code within the if body.

Comment: @nos it == dutyAndJob.end() is true when the name is not in the map, so if I wanted to enter the if statement if the name isn't in the map(which is what I am trying to achieve), I would just use it == dutyAndJob.end(); would I not?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that Job is the key, and Name is the data.  The way you have it structured, you can only use find on the Job that will retrieve the Name.

```
   string job = "Cashier";

   it = dutyAndJob.find(job);
   if (it == dutyAndJob.end())
   {
       cout << "Testing : " << job<< endl;
   }
```

If you actually wanted to search by Name, maybe the Name should be the key, and the Job should be the data?